# Another Equivalence of connected space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, connectedness

If A is a topological space and $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. We can show that if A is connected, then $\forall a,b \in f[A]$ such that $a \leq b$ then $[a,b] \subseteq f[A]$?

Comment: What is $y$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $y=b$. Observe that connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals. So, $f[A]$ is nothing but an interval (being a continuous image of a connected set), say $I$. Now, if $I$ contains $a$ and $b$, then being an interval, $I$ contains all the points in between. In particular, $[a,b]\subseteq I=f[A]$, which completes your proof.